# Social Plugins for Facebook Photos and Albums

Tags: comments, photo, facebook-social-plugins

Is it possible to use Social Plugins such as the Comments and Like plugins to display the comments and likes for a photo or album uploaded to Facebook?

I have tried various URLs for the HREF attribute (the photo source, the photo page, the graph URL, etc) and cannot get the plugin to display existing comments against the photo. Can someone suggest the correct URL (if any) that I should use?

I can get access to the list of comments using the graph API, however I would prefer to make use of the social plugins if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can not use them in that manner.  You can use the graph api to read and write comments, read and add albums and photos.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api

This is somewhat involved and requires knowledge of coding.

I personally have been working on a Feed for the wall, and for albums and have to say it was no easy task.  https://apps.facebook.com/AnotherFeed

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer. Thanks.